# Proving that the projection on smooth manifolds is a submersion

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

> **Proposition**: Let M be a smooth manifold and let $\pi:TM\to M$ be the projection to M, i.e, $\pi(p,v_p)=p$.
>
> Then p is smooth and a submersion.

I found the following proof in another thread that the natural projection is smooth:

> Let $\pi:T(X)\to X$, be the projection map in question.
>
> Let $U\subset T(X)$ be a neighborhood of some $(x',v')\in T(X)$ and $V\subset X$ a neighborhood of $\pi(x',v')=x'\in X$. We know that there exists a chart $\psi:V\to \psi(V)\subset \mathbb R^k$.
>
> Let $\phi:U\to \phi(U)\in\mathbb R^{2k}$ be a local coordinate chart for $T(X)$ where for any $(x,v)\in U$, $\phi((x,v))=(x_1,\ldots,x_k,\ldots, x_{2k})$ where $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\psi(x)$ for some $x\in V$. In that case, notice that the following diagram commutes
> $\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
> \newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
> \newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}$
> \begin{array}{c}
> U & \ra{\pi|_U} & V \\
> \da{\phi} & & \da{\psi} \\
> \phi(U) & \ras{\nu} & \psi(V) \\
> \end{array}
> where $\nu:\phi(U)\to\psi(V)$ is the canonical submersion i.e, $$\nu(x_1,\ldots,x_k,\ldots, x_{2k})=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\psi(x)$$
> Clearly, $\psi\circ \pi|_U\circ \phi^{-1}=\nu$. Thus by the [local submersion theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1320102/11470), $\pi$ is a submersion at $(x',v')$. Since our proof was independent of the choice of $(x',v')$, we conclude that $\pi$ is a submersion everywhere in $T(X)$

However I am not understanding how the author applies the local submersion theorem. I think the author is making the reverse implication that is if $v$ is the canonical projection then $\pi$ is a submersion. But the theorem states the other way around. The version I am familiar with is the following:
Local Submersion theorem: Consider $\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}^{m_1}\times\mathbb{R}^{m_2}$ and let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ open with $p\in U$. Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^{m_2}$ such that $D_2 f(p)$ is a linear isomorphism.
Then, there is an open neighborhood $V_p\subseteq U$ of $p$,  and an open set $w_p$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi:w_p\to V_p$ such that $f\circ\phi=\pi_2$.

**Questions**:

How do I finish this proof? How do I apply the local submersion theorem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to apply the local submersion theorem. $\nu$ *is* the canonical submersion, and $\pi|_U = \psi^{-1}\circ\nu\circ\phi$. This equation tells you that $d(\pi|_U)$ is surjective.